Can't access properties of token
I'm working with React Native. I'm using AsyncStorage to save users' tokens, but when I try to access the properties of said token, it marks them as undefined. Here's my code:
useEffect(() => {
  const getTokenAndDecode = async () => {
    try {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
      if (token) {
        const parts = token.split('.');
        const decodedToken = base64.decode(parts[1]);
        console.log('Decoded token:', decodedToken);
        if (decodedToken.userId) {
          setUserId(decodedToken.userId);
        } else {
          console.log("UserID doesn't exist.");
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching token:', error);
    }
  };

  getTokenAndDecode();
}, []);

I get a message saying UserID doesn't exist, but it clearly is there, so I don't know what to do. I tried parsing the token to JSON, but I get an error:

Error parsing token: [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected character: ]


Seems to me you're simply missing JSON.parse(base64.decode(parts[1])) but what is the format of base64.decode(parts[1])? You can run it through https://jsonlint.com to check for problems

Yeah, I was going to suggest same thing,  decoded token might be a string, maybe try
const decodedToken = JSON.parse(decodedTokenString);

The decoded Token gives me the following: {"userId":1,"email":"pipa@test.com","iat":1712582806,"exp":1712586406}. My friend pointed out it was already a JSON, and when trying typeof it marks it as a String. I tried parsing the decoded token const decodedToken = JSON.parse('{"userId":1,"email":"pipa@test.com","iat":1712582806,"exp":1712586406}'), and it worked! But when I try to do it with the decodedToken as it is, it doesn't work.
